# Memoization table not working

Tags: java, memoization

I have got the non-memoization code working correctly, which computes the number of ways 'n' can be represented given m possible values. But I can't figure out in the code below why the memoization table memoNM is returning 0 instead of the answer which in this case is 242. The table memoNM is just storing previously computed values in the recursion tree for faster lookup. Can someone please help me?

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class coinChange {
    //Find all ways of representing n in given m inputs
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Integer> coinTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(25,
                10, 5, 1));//m
        int n = 100;
        int[][] memoNM = new int[n + 1][coinTypes.size() + 1];
        // Initialize memoNM

        for (int i = 0; i < memoNM.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < memoNM[0].length; j++) {
                memoNM[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        int ans = coinChange.coinChange1(n, coinTypes, 0, memoNM);
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

    public static int coinChange1(int n, ArrayList<Integer> coinTypes,
            int indexFrom, int[][] memoNM) {
        // System.out.println("Coin Types: " + coinTypes.toString() + ", n is: "
        // + n + ", m is : " + coinTypes.size());
        if (n < 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (indexFrom >= coinTypes.size()) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (memoNM[n][indexFrom] > 0) {
            return memoNM[n][indexFrom];
        }

        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        /*System.out.println("n is: " + n + " m is: "
                + (coinTypes.size() - indexFrom) + ", memo[n][m] is: "
                + memoNM[n][indexFrom]);
*/
        memoNM[n][indexFrom] += coinChange1(n - coinTypes.get(indexFrom),
                coinTypes, indexFrom, memoNM);
        ++indexFrom;
        memoNM[n][indexFrom] += coinChange1(n, coinTypes, indexFrom, memoNM);
        return memoNM[n][indexFrom];
    }
}
```

Update:
I implemented the same code above using a HashMap as a lookup instead of a table and yet my answer is wrong. The correct  answer for n=6 and m = 4 should be 9

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class coinChangeMap {
    // For an excellent explanation see section 1.7.5 in
    // http://composingprograms.com/pages/17-recursive-functions.html
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Integer> coinTypes = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4,
                3, 2, 1));
        int n = 6;
        HashMap<Tuple, Integer> memoMap = new HashMap<Tuple, Integer>();

        int ans = coinChangeMap1(n, coinTypes, 0, memoMap);
    memoMap.toString();
    System.out.println(ans);

}

public static int coinChangeMap1(int n, ArrayList<Integer> coinTypes,
        int indexFrom, HashMap<Tuple, Integer> memoMap) {
    // System.out.println("Coin Types: " + coinTypes.toString() + ", n is: "
    // + n + ", m is : " + coinTypes.size());
    if (n < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (indexFrom >= coinTypes.size()) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    Tuple tup = new Tuple(n, indexFrom);
    if (memoMap.containsKey(tup)) {
        return memoMap.get(tup);
    }
    /*
     * System.out.println("n is: " + n + " m is: " + (coinTypes.size() -
     * indexFrom) + ", memo[n][m] is: " + memoNM[n][indexFrom]);
     */
    int leftAns = coinChangeMap1(n - coinTypes.get(indexFrom), coinTypes,
            indexFrom, memoMap);
    // memoMap.put(new Tuple(n,indexFrom), leftAns);

    int rightAns = coinChangeMap1(n, coinTypes, ++indexFrom, memoMap);
    memoMap.put(new Tuple(n, indexFrom), leftAns + rightAns);

    return memoMap.get(new Tuple(n, indexFrom));
}
```

}

My class Tuple is:

```
public class Tuple {

    int n;
int idxFrom;
public Tuple(int n, int indexFrom) {
    this.n = n;
    this.idxFrom = indexFrom;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(!(other instanceof Tuple)){
        return false;
    }
    Tuple o = (Tuple)other;
    return ((this.n == o.n) && (this.idxFrom == o.idxFrom));
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    int hashCode = 1;
    hashCode = 37 * hashCode + this.n + this.idxFrom;
    return hashCode;
}
}
```

Comment: perhaps showing the code of what worked before, this way we can see where you might have gone wrong in your refactoring to the memoization

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this is the only problem, but one problem is that indexFrom is being incremented between the two recursive calls.  In the array based version, this results in the two answers not getting added together.  The hashmap version adds to two values together, but is likely storing the result with the wrong key.